# Error when check/Build a created R package "LOGICAL() can only be applied to a 'logical', not a 'integer'"

Tags: r, build, r-package

I'm building a R package with devtools, but when I try to check the project, I get this error

> "Error in poll(list(self), ms) :    LOGICAL() can only be applied to a
>   'logical', not a 'integer'".

I've tried to remake the package from the start, but I am still getting the same error.

```
==> devtools::check(document = FALSE)

-- Building --------------------------------------------------------------- Svect --
Setting env vars:
* CFLAGS    : -Wall -pedantic
* CXXFLAGS  : -Wall -pedantic
* CXX11FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error in poll(list(self), ms) : 
  LOGICAL() can only be applied to a 'logical', not a 'integer'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... run_manage -> <Anonymous> -> process_poll_io -> poll

Exited with status 1.
```

Comment: The `SEXP` you are passing down identifies itself as an integer, at the C level you cannot force that to be logical.  Remedy: cast in R before descending.  Or, of course, assign to an `int` instead and go from there.

Comment: I received the same error when using {devtools} v2.0.02.  I created a new library, re-installed {devtools} and my package’s dependencies, and then checked my package.  Did not receive the error.  This could be a build issue with {devtools}.